# Error in Migration (DBCONTEXT File) in EF CodeFirst for NetCore for Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I work with EF CodeFirt in NET Framework (Winforms) and NET Core (Web) without problems.

But with EF CodeFirst i have a error when throw a new migration:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Data.AppDbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\Data\AppDbContext.cs:line 29

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDbContext" connectionString="<ConnectionString>"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

APPDBCONTEXT

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {        
        public DbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDbContext"].ConnectionString);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UnitConfiguration());            
        }
    }
```

Because is WINFORMS don't exists STARTUP.CS or APPSETTINGS.JSON for configure how a service, I don't know what do.

I try many searches and many solutions in the web but the error persist.

Comment: Have you checked that `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDbContext"]` actually returns `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection`?

Comment: The problem dont is NullReferenceException because the error is with the parameter optionsBuilder

Comment: Yes, i validated ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDbContext"] and is correct the value from APP.CONFIG

Comment: How do you initialize/create your context? I was not able to reproduce the beahviour in simple console app. Can you add `Unit` class and `UnitConfiguration`?

Comment: Initialize the context i think is the problem. In Winforms with NetFramework is in the constructor; in web with Net Core is in Startup (ConfigureServices) but in WinForms with Net Core i dont know where do it. Obviusly dont is possible in the constructor with a string or with Configure Service method.

Comment: I have an example were in app.config the app settings define server and default catelog [here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/ef-core-projections/blob/master/ConsoleLoggingExample/App.config#L71) and read in  [shown here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/ef-core-projections/blob/master/ConsoleLoggingExample/Contexts/NorthWindContext.cs#L60)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with help [Karen Payne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5509738/karen-payne) sample and support from [Guru Stron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron). Thanks!!

The problem was in OnConfiguring method because for any reason the ConnectionString in method UseSqlServer are NULL.

If i read from APP.CONFIG file in windows form the value is correct but in OnConfiguring method are NULL.

The solution (no the best solution) was use one string for ConnectionString parameter and Migration work.

Now wait read ConnectionString parameter from APP.CONFIG file and complete the DbContext class.

Attach the code

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            //ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; //
            string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=REF_SIGIPRO;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
```